# How to get the unique tags of the posts under a category in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I have a pretty novice question to ask the experts. I need to get the unique tags of the posts which are under a specific category.

To be more clear let's assume I have 30 categories of posts. From them I take the category Car and this category has 30 posts under it. Again assume I have 100+ 'post tags' and these 30 posts under Cars category are tagged under 35 tags.

How can i get those 35 tags by using the category "Car"?

I can perform raw database queries seeking the tag list, but I'm interested in some more elegant and proper way to do this.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround is to write custom SQL query and fetch all tags at once. Any other approach which uses WP core functions will generate tons of small SQL queries, what is redundant.

Use this query to fetch all category tags:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pt.term_id, pt.name
  FROM wp_terms AS t
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS ptr ON ptr.object_id = tr.object_id AND ptr.term_taxonomy_id <> tr.term_taxonomy_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS ptt ON ptt.term_taxonomy_id = ptr.term_taxonomy_id AND ptt.taxonomy = 'post_tag'
  LEFT JOIN wp_terms AS pt ON pt.term_id = ptt.term_id
 WHERE t.name = 'Car' AND tt.taxonomy = 'category' AND pt.term_id IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY pt.term_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to achieve all unique tags according to the product category. Add the below code into functions.php and use this hook anywhere that you want. do_action( 'archive_tag_filters_action');

```
function archive_tag_filters_callback() {
$category = get_queried_object();

$args = array(
    'post_type'             => 'product',
    'post_status'           => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'        => '-1',
    'tax_query'             => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
            'field'         => 'id', 
            'terms'         =>  $category->term_id, //category id
            'operator'      => 'IN' 
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$term_array = $tags_unique  = array();

while( $query->have_posts() ) {
      $query->the_post();
      
      $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_tag' );
      if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                 $term_array[] = array(
                    'term_text' => $term->name,
                    "term_link" => get_term_link( $term )
                 );
             }
      }
}


foreach ($term_array as $row) {
    $tags_unique[$row['term_text']] = $row;
}

$current_tags = array_values($tags_unique);

if ( $current_tags ) {
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach ( $current_tags as $term ) {
      echo '<li>';
      echo '<a href="' . $term['term_link'] . '">';
      echo $term['term_text'];
      echo '</a>';
      echo '</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
else{
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>No results.</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}
}
add_action( 'archive_tag_filters_action', 'archive_tag_filters_callback', 10, 2 );
```